# Detect chrome start on background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote this code that start event when chrome start.
But it doesn't work.
Please advise me and give code.

background.js

```
var judgeFirst = 0;
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function() {
    chrome.windows.getAll({}, function(windows) {
        // execute only when chrome start
        if (windows.length === 1 && judgeFirst === 0) {
            console.log("start!");
            judgeFirst++;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you want to detect it only with `windows.length`? Would detecting it another way be acceptable?

Comment: No, I don't. I want to know every way.

Comment: Chrome commonly restore previous tabs/windows on start so `windows.length === 1` will frequently have false negatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is [chrome.runtime.onStartup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup). This event will trigger anytime your extension starts which should only occur when the browser starts, when your extension gets installed, when your extension gets re-enabled, and when your extension gets updated.